# How to submit form data in bootstrap for PHP?

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using PHP form element : the submit button as

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value"set"/>
```

and the form was being submitted like :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'set'){..do something..}
```

Now in bootstrap a submit button is usually written as

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">set</button>
```

My question is how to submit this form data since I cannot do it like the previous way. It might be a noob question but I am new to bootstrap. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: add a hidden input with name `submit`? Check other fields in `$_POST` array?

Comment: There are ample (bootstrap) scripts out there using what you're wanting to do; you just need to spend some time looking for them.

Comment: what is this line expected to do `$_POST['submit'] == 'set'`? Why in the world you will use `isset($_POST['submit'])` when you have `$_POST['submit'] = 'set'`

Comment: use to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value"set" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"/>`

Answer (score 1):

This has little to do with bootstrap.  You  can set a name and value attribute on a button as well as an input[submit].

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="submit" value="set">
    set
</button>
```